# Where can I find a dataset containing scientific research papers on different topics?

Tags: nlp, dataset

I am trying to find a dataset containing scientific papers from different domains of interest (e.g., neuroscience, mathematics, physics, history, biology, medicine, etc.) in order to develop an NLP project intended to summarize scientific texts while changing domain-specific terms into more common words.

Does anybody know where I could find such a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The 5GB data set provided byarmancohan [should do.](https://github.com/armancohan/long-summarization)

as he notes:

> Two datasets of long and structured documents (scientific papers) are
> provided. The datasets are obtained from ArXiv and PubMed OpenAccess
> repositories.

or get it straight from [TensorFlow datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/scientific_papers).